# inner product of matrix multiplication

Tags: matrices, inner-products, transpose

I've seen a few times this property:

$$ <AB, AB> = <A^tAB, B>$$

Is there any proof for this? Can anyone point me to some more material regarding inner-products of matrices?

Comment: Are you talking about the Frobenius / Hilbert-Schmidt inner product? If so, it's defined by $\langle X,Y\rangle=\mathrm{tr}(X^TY)$ (or with conjugate-transpose for complex matrices). Then it becomes pretty straightforward once you know what the inner product is...

Comment: But isn't the definition of transposition just that $\langle ^tf(x),y\rangle=\langle x,f(y)\rangle$ ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose_of_a_linear_map

Comment: @zwim That is indeed the definition of transposition. However it involves the inner product of vectors, not the inner product of matrices. Not quite the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the inner-product of two matrices is no different than that of two vectors, i.e., the inner-product of $\newcommand{\reals}{\mathbb{R}}A, B\in\reals^{m\times n}$ is
\begin{equation}
<A,B> = \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij} B_{ij}.
\end{equation}

Now it is straightforward to prove that
\begin{equation}
\newcommand{\trace}{\mathbf{Tr}}
<A,B> = \trace \left(A^T B\right).
\end{equation}

Therefore if we use the fact that $(AB)^T = B^T A^T$, we have
\begin{equation}
<AB,AB> = \trace \left( (AB)^T AB \right) = \trace \left(A^T AB\right)^TB = <A^T AB, B>,
\end{equation}
hence the proof!

Comment: @runway44 Thx! I added that fact to the answer.